# SQL Query with Aggregate Count, where at least 1 of the counts has a value in a field

Tags: sql-server-2008, aggregate, query

```
SELECT PERSON_ID,COUNT(APPL_ID) COUNTS
FROM APPLICATIONS
GROUP BY PERSON_ID
ORDER BY COUNTS DESC
```

The above query returns all persons who have applied for all time (essentially a count of the whole table).
I want a clause to limit this to persons who have applied this year, yet still show the count of ALL their applications...
IE, a person may have applied in 2018 once, but they've applied 20 times total thus the results would be similar. Skipping over id's 1,2, 4-11.

```
ID | COUNT
---+------- 
003|     20
---+------- 
012|      4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you can do it using a subquery, something like:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID, COUNT(APPL_ID) COUNTS
FROM APPLICATIONS
WHERE PERSON_ID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT PERSON_ID
    FROM APPLICATIONS
    WHERE APPL_DATE > 2018-01-01
)
GROUP BY PERSON_ID
ORDER BY COUNTS DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on indexes etc. this should provide slightly lower I/O:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID, COUNTS = COUNT(APPL_ID)
FROM dbo.APPLICATIONS
GROUP BY PERSON_ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN APPL_DATE >= '20180101' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
ORDER BY COUNTS DESC;
```